# Is it possible to run chromedriver on win 10 using portable chrome?

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, portability

I have fresh new win 10 pro PC. w/o any google apps. and w/o any bluetooth card/devices.
I have installed last Intelij IDEA + chromedriver + chromeportable from portableapps.com

and when I run my code (as admin)

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("D:\\Program Files\\ChromePortable\\ChromePortable.exe");
        options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=d:\\Documents\\Temp\\"); // If I comment this I get sandbox error
//        options.addArguments("--disable-features=WebBluetooth");
//        options.addArguments("--headless"); // Run Chrome in headless mode
//        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
 
        // Create a WebDriver instance with the specified options.
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
 
        // Navigate to Google.
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
```

I get error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51790/devtools/browser/43cdaac2-0bcb-4785-ad8f-b6a8717d0657
[3884:10284:0922/175934.295:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [17:59:34.295] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

when I run w/o admin rights I get error

```
Failed to grant sandbox access to network context data directory D:\Program Files\ChromePortable\Data\profile\Default\Network: Access is denied. (0x5)
```

PS: When I have the same config on win 7 I could easily ran chromedriver

run with and without administrator.
run with and without argument options